# Cannot get selectedIndex from select element positioned in cell in hidden row

Tags: javascript, html, dom, select, datatables

I'm using DataTable and I'm trying to get some filtering function working with select element positioned in cells of the table.

The filtering works by entering text in input field positioned below each column. Then the filter function checks the selected text in all cells of that column and if no match is found in one cell, related row is hidden.

When the table has been loaded, it works to filter the table once. The problem is when clearing the filter, then it doesn't work. The reason seems to be related to that I'm using selectedIndex for the select DOM objects positioned in the rows that are not visible for the moment.

"qu_owner_xxx" is the ID of the select elements.

```
var el1 = document.getElementById("qu_owner_4");     //Visible, works like a charm
console.log("ID 1 " + el1.id);                       //ID is printed
console.log("EL 1 " + el1.selectedIndex);                           
var el2 = document.getElementById("qu_owner_17");    //Hidden, returns null
console.log("ID 2 " + el2.id);                       //Not reaching here
console.log("EL 2 " + el2.selectedIndex) ;           //Not reaching here
str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;             //Just for showing how to get the string used for filtering later
```

The thing is that the data of the cell is passed to the filter function as pure html, not as object. I can get the id from that part doing *$(aData[i2]).attr('id')* where aData is the table row. But using jQuery there seems to be some information you cannot reach compared to using the actual DOM object (e.g. selectedIndex), especially when you have to "recreate" the object from html.

How can I get the text from the selected value of the hidden select box/row? Is it even possible?

---

**UPDATE**

I tested my theory in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92Wg8/1/), but it actually works retrieving the information from the hidden row/select. But it's no question about it, in my filter function is the rows that are not displayed that's failing.

My filter function (DataTable is calling this function when it is time for filtering)

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
                function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {

                var ret = true;    

                    //Loop through all input fields i tfoot that has class 'sl_filter' attached                                              
                   $('tfoot .sl_filter').each(function(i, obj){

                       //$(this) can be used. Get the index of this colum.
                       var i2 = $("tfoot input").index($(this));                           

                       //Create regexp to math
                       var r = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i");

                       var str = "";
                       if(i2 == 5){//This is just during development, don't want to care about other columns with select element so just doing things on this column

                            //Here I just pick two id, one that I know is visible and one that is not
                           var el1 = document.getElementById("qu_owner_4");     //Visible, works like a charm
                           console.log("ID 1 " + el1.id);                       //ID is printed
                           console.log("EL 1 " + el1.selectedIndex);            //selectedIndex is printed            
                           var el2 = document.getElementById("qu_owner_17");    //Hidden, returns null
                           console.log("ID 2 " + el2.id);                       //Not reaching here
                           console.log("EL 2 " + el2.selectedIndex) ;           //Not reaching here

                           //This is how I intended to get it working, but fail
                           var el = document.getElementById($(aData[i2]).attr('id'));                                                      
                           str = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text; //String to be used for comparing

                       }

                       /*Test to see if there is a match or if the input value is the default 
                         (the initial value of input before it has any fokus/text) */                           
                       if(r.test(str) || $(this).val()=="Search"){
                           //Return true only exits this function
                           return true;
                       }else{

                           /*Return false returns both function an .each. Retain 'false' in a variable scoped
                             to be reached outside the .each */                                
                           ret = false;
                           return false;
                       }
                   });
                   //Return true or false
                    return ret;                        
                }
            );
```

aData = the row. aData[x] gives me the cell content of cell x on that row. For the select element it's the raw html.

this = the input field in which the search string i entered.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can have the text from the selected value !
Here is one way (probably not the best, but works) :

```
    $('select').change(function() {
       var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
       var selectedText = '';

       jQuery(this).children('option').each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).val() == selectedValue) {
             selectedText = jQuery(this).text();
          }
       });
    });
```

The `selectedText` variable will contain the text from the selected value.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hhGut/).

Comment: Thanks! But as described, in the filter function I get the data as pure html and need to in some way get access to the text from there. It's in the filter function I do the filtering. It's easy in the change function. But as I also described, the rows with the fields are hidden, hence you cannot even change the value of the select.

Comment: Sorry, read it too fast.. So, can you paste the code of your filter function ?

Comment: No problem. Filter function is included now. I made a jsfiddle to try to recreate the problem, with unexpected result. Details in my update.